# Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, xstate, xstate-react

```
export const bulkWatchPayload = (requestIds = [], currentView) => {
  const structuredData = requestIds.map(
    (requestId) => `ukca_${requestId}_${currentView}`
  )
  
  return {
    userId: getCurrentUserEmailId(),
    correlationId,
    entityType: `ukca-list-view-page`,
    entities: requestIds
  }
}
```

```
 socket.emit(
          SocketEvents.REPLACE_WATCH,
          bulkWatchPayload(e.data.requestIds, e.data.currentView)
        )
```

requestIds =[123,345,1231,3423]
structuredData= ['ukca_123_mainPage','ukca_343_firstPage']

if i assign requestIds to entities working fine but if i assign structuredData to entities this error popping up **'Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked'**

it should work if i assign structuredData to entities too

Comment: How does `bulkWatchPayload()` get called? Does the error occur inside `bulkWatchPayload()` or in a different function?

Comment: added the code of how bulkWatchPayload is getting called @DennisKats

Comment: not sure where exactly the error getting caused, if we assign Array of numbers its working fine and if we assign array of strings error getting poped up